# CDF of a random variables

Tags: probability

[image]

[image]

I get that the x represents the money, but where does the 1/12, 1/3, and 1/6 come from?

Answer (score 1):

It comes from the first paragraph.

The player wins 2 dollars when the die lands showing `1` or `2`. The probability for this is $1/3$.$$\mathsf P(X=2)=\tfrac 13$$

The player wins 3 dollars when the die lands showing `3` or `4`. The probability for this is $1/3$.$$\mathsf P(X=3)=\tfrac 13$$

The player wins 5 dollars when the die lands showing `5`. The probability for this is $1/6$.$$\mathsf P(X=5)=\tfrac 16$$

The player wins 10 dollars when the die lands showing `6` *and* a fair coin lands showing heads. The probability for this is $1/12$.$$\mathsf P(X=10)=\tfrac 1{12}$$

The player wins 0 dollars when the die lands showing `6` *and* a fair coin lands showing tails. The probability for this is $1/12$.$$\mathsf P(X=0)=\tfrac 1{12}$$

Comment: I see it now the 1/3 and 1/6 come from the dice. The 1/12 come from dice and coin. Thanks.

Comment: Please take the habit to validate good answers given weeks and weeks ago.